# Running Image Matching service with FaceNet on GPU using GUNICORN and FLASK issue

Tags: tensorflow, flask, gpu, gunicorn, gevent

I'm trying to create an inference server using FLASK APIs for the Facenet model for an image matching task. I'm using Gunicorn for scaling the server and the server gets images from the client using a POST request in the form of a string sequence. The server gets that image and matches it with an image from a mongodb database and finds the distance.

The server makes calls for tensorflow to load the model when the app is run using Gunicorn and it creates gunicorn worker instances which I can see using `nvidia-smi pmon` but when I'm sending calls to this server using a client, only the GPU 0 is being utilised and even that is not being utilised as much as I'm able to use when I run it without a server/client. 
My gunicorn call is using the `gevent` worker-class and my call looks like this:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --timeout 1000000 -w 4 -k gevent wsgi:app
```

I have 4 GPUs and when my server runs in the above call, the `nvidia-smi pmon` output is as follows:

```
0      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93719     C     3     0     0     0   python         
1      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
# gpu    pid  type    sm   mem   enc   dec   command
# Idx      #   C/G     %     %     %     %   name
0      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93719     C     2     0     0     0   python         
1      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
1      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
2      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
3      93719     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93715     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93716     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93717     C     0     0     0     0   python         
0      93719     C     3     0     0     0   python
```

As can be seen above, only GPU 0 is getting all the calls and that too only with around 3-5% usage. My test code without a server-client model is able to reach 25% usage directly on each GPU.
Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong or anything else that I should try?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of only the 1st GPU got used is that by default, even if Tensorflow can see all 4 GPUs, it will only use the 1st one.

Here although Gunicorn sent several calls and each call tries to invoke its Tensorflow, they all see 4 GPUs and use the 1st one.

I think one possible solutions is to have 4 different Flask or gunicorns that configured with environment varible "CUDA_VISIBLE_DIVICES" be 0, 1, 2, 3 respectively. Then you should use Nginx to forward api calls to these 4 servers.

I'm not sure about the reasons of low GPU mem usage.

Comment: I actually modified in config.gpu_options the argument for visible devices and I was able to force each worker to pick a GPU but I still wasn't able to solve the low usage issue.